# Do you need to define variables even if they will be changed?

Tags: python, discord.py

When running the code I get an error that rank, highelo and nextrank are not defined.  Do I need to set default values before like

```
rank = "unranked"
highelo = 0
nextrank = "unranked"
```

Or is there another way

```
rankcalc = "You are in {}\nYou are about {} games away from {}.\n*I am not always correct*".format(rank, math.floor((highelo - int(arg)) / 8 + 1), nextrank)

@bot.command()
async def ovo (ctx, arg):
 if 0<int(arg)<153:
   highelo = 153
   rank = "Bronze 1"
   nextrank = "Bronze 2"
   await ctx.send(rankcalc)
```

Comment: Yes, you need to establish the variables before referencing them.

Comment: Or move your rankcalc string into your `ovo` function so it's not actually executed before.

Comment: the only reason I didn't want to put the string in there was because I plan on copying the if statement a few times for different numbers so I thought that it would be neater to only put the variables there

Comment: ``rankcalc`` is evaluated *immediately* in the *global scope*; it is not a function that gets evaluated lazily in ``ovo``.

Comment: Only problem is now when using the function it does not modify the defaults that I have now put

Answer (score 0):

You defined your Variables inside the command, which is basically an asynchronous function. Variables defined in functions cannot be used outside, so therefor you need to either define the Variables outside of the command or define rankcalc in the command. Here's a quick example:

```
# Won't work, because rankcalc is defined outside the command

rankcalc = "You are in {}\nYou are about {} games away from {}.\n*I am not always correct*".format(rank, math.floor((highelo - int(arg)) / 8 + 1), nextrank)

@bot.command()
async def ovo (ctx, arg):
    if 0<int(arg)<153:
        highelo = 153
        rank = "Bronze 1"
        nextrank = "Bronze 2"
        await ctx.send(rankcalc)
```

---

```
# Will work, because rankcalc is defined after the other variables and is defined in the function, so it can refer to them

rankcalc = "You are in {}\nYou are about {} games away from {}.\n*I am not always correct*".format(rank, math.floor((highelo - int(arg)) / 8 + 1), nextrank)

@bot.command()
async def ovo (ctx, arg):
   if 0<int(arg)<153:
       highelo = 153
       rank = "Bronze 1"
       nextrank = "Bronze 2"
       rankcalc = "You are in {}\nYou are about {} games away from {}.\n*I am not always correct*".format(rank, math.floor((highelo - int(arg)) / 8 + 1), nextrank)
       await ctx.send(rankcalc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should always define your variables , it's a lot safer especially for younger programmers.

Comment: Only problem is now that when I've defined the variables it uses them instead the of the changed variables in the function